# How to declare the type of a function that returns an array in Fortran?

Tags: fortran

I have function that returns an array, say

```
function f(A)
    implicit none
    real, intent(in) :: A(5)
    real, intent(out) :: f(5)

    f = A+1
end
```

My question is, how can I define `f` in the main program unit?  E.g.

```
program main
    implicit none
    real :: A(5)
    real, dimension(5), external :: f  ! does not work

    ...
end
```

Comment: For a function returning an array an _explicit interface_ is required.  See, for example, http://stackoverflow.com/q/24910843/3157076.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need an explicit interface.  You can do this in a few ways.

1. Explicitly in the scoping unit that calls `f`:

   ```
   interface
     function f(A)
       implicit none
       real, intent(in) :: A(5)
       real :: f(5)
     end function
   end interface
   ```
2. Place the function in your program host scope as an internal function:

   ```
    program main
       ...
    contains
      function f(A)
        implicit none
        real, intent(in) :: A(5)
        real :: f(5)

        f = A+1
      end
    end program
   ```
3. Place the function in a module:

   ```
    module A
    contains
      function f(A)
        implicit none
        real, intent(in) :: A(5)
        real :: f(5)

        f = A+1
      end
    end module

    program main
      use A
      ...
    end program
   ```
4. Use the explicit interface from a different procedure with the same arguments and return type, kind and rank.

   ```
   program main
     interface
       function r5i_r5o(r5)
         implicit none
         real, intent(in) :: r5(5)
         real :: r5i_r5o(5)
       end function
     end interface

     procedure(r5i_r5o) :: f
     ...
   end program

   function f(A)
     implicit none
     real, intent(in) :: A(5)
     real :: f(5)

     f = A+1
   end
   ```

The cleanest way of doing this is option #3 using modules.  This gives you the benefit of an automatic explicit interface (not needing to do option #1 everywhere you call `f`) and makes your function available everywhere the module is used rather than limited to a specific scoping unit as in option #2.  Option #4 can be handy if you have many procedures with the same argument and return types since one explicit interface can be re-used for all of them.

Answer (score 1):

This shows three different ways to specify function results, and how to use modules to organize your functions:

```
module so_func

    INTEGER, PARAMETER :: MAX_SIZE = 5

    TYPE MY_DATA
        INTEGER :: SIZE
        REAL, DIMENSION(MAX_SIZE) :: DATA
    ENDTYPE


contains

    FUNCTION f1(A,N) RESULT(X)
    implicit none
    INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: N
    REAL, INTENT(IN) :: A(N)
    REAL :: X(N)
    ! ....
    X = 1.0+A
    END FUNCTION f1

    TYPE(MY_DATA) FUNCTION f2(A,N)
    implicit none
    INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: N
    REAL, INTENT(IN) :: A(N)
    ! ....
    f2%SIZE = N
    f2%DATA(1:N) = 1.0+A
    END FUNCTION f2

    FUNCTION f3(A,N)
    implicit none
    INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: N
    REAL, INTENT(IN) :: A(N)
    REAL :: f3(N)
    ! ....
    f3 = 1.0+A
    END FUNCTION f3

end module


program SO_RESULT
    use so_func
    implicit none
    integer, parameter :: n=5
    REAL :: A(n), y1(n), y3(n)    
    TYPE(MY_DATA) :: y2
    INTEGER :: i
    ! Variables

    A =(/ (i, i=1,n) /)

    y1 = f1(A,n)
    y2 = f2(A,n)
    y3 = f3(A,n)


end program SO_RESULT
```