# Number of subscripts is incorrect - Fortran

Tags: fortran

```
program Duffing

        implicit none

        !########## Constants and Variable ############!
        
        real, parameter :: pi =  4.0*ATAN(1.0)
        
        real :: omega, k, B, s_start, s_end
        real :: alpha, beta
        real :: T, Ndim, ds
        real, dimension(2) :: calc_derivative
        
        ! Temp
        
        real, dimension(2) :: y, a
        real :: s, temp
        
        !########## Variables assignment ############!
        
        omega   = 0.905
        k       = 0.0455
        B       = 0.0
        s_start = 0.0
        s_end   = 1800.0
        
        alpha   =  1.0
        beta    = -1.0
        
        T       = 2.0 * pi / omega
        Ndim    = 50.0
        ds      = T/Ndim
        
        ! Temp
        y = (/1.0,2.0/)
        s = 1.0

        a = calc_derivative(y, s, B, k, alpha, beta, omega)
 
        print *, "Result = ", a(1)
        read *, temp
        
    end program Duffing
    
    

    !######### Function defenitions ##########!
    
    
    ! Function to calculate derivatives
    
    function calc_derivative(y, s, B, k, alpha, beta, omega) 
    
        implicit none
        
        ! Local variables
        
        real, dimension(2) :: calc_derivative
        real :: psi, psi_dot, psi_dot_dot
        
        ! Local variables receiving arguments from main 
        
        real, dimension(2) :: y
        real :: s, B, k, alpha, beta, omega

        psi          = y(1)
        psi_dot      = y(2)
        psi_dot_dot  = B * COS(omega * s) - k*psi_dot - alpha*psi - beta*(psi ** 3.0)
        
        calc_derivative(1) = psi_dot
        calc_derivative(2) = psi_dot_dot
        
        return
        
    end function calc_derivative
```

Can somebody kindly help me to understand why the error ' The number of subscripts is incorrect. [calc_derivative]' is appearing. I have rechecked the function call signature several times.

**A point to note is that the function calc_derivative is returning an array. If I try to return a scalar from the function as shown below then no error (it is just an example, not what I need).**

```
    program Duffing

        implicit none

        !########## Constants and Variable ############!
        
        real, parameter :: pi =  4.0*ATAN(1.0)
        
        real :: omega, k, B, s_start, s_end
        real :: alpha, beta
        real :: T, Ndim, ds
        real :: calc_derivative
        
        ! Temp
        
        real, dimension(2) :: y, a
        real :: s, temp
        
        !########## Variables assignment ############!
        
        omega   = 0.905
        k       = 0.0455
        B       = 0.0
        s_start = 0.0
        s_end   = 1800.0
        
        alpha   =  1.0
        beta    = -1.0
        
        T       = 2.0 * pi / omega
        Ndim    = 50.0
        ds      = T/Ndim
        
        ! Temp
        y = (/1.0,2.0/)
        s = 1.0

        a(1) = calc_derivative(y, s, B, k, alpha, beta, omega)
 
        print *, "Result = ", a(1)
        read *, temp
        
    end program Duffing
    
    

    !######### Function defenitions ##########!
    
    
    ! Function to calculate derivatives
    
    function calc_derivative(y, s, B, k, alpha, beta, omega) 
    
        implicit none
        
        ! Local variables
        
        real :: calc_derivative
        real :: psi, psi_dot, psi_dot_dot
        
        ! Local variables receiving arguments from main 
        
        real, dimension(2) :: y
        real :: s, B, k, alpha, beta, omega
        

        psi          = y(1)
        psi_dot      = y(2)
        psi_dot_dot  = B * COS(omega * s) - k*psi_dot - alpha*psi - beta*(psi ** 3.0)
        
        calc_derivative = psi_dot
        
        return
        
    end function calc_derivative
```

I want to understand why the problem occurs when I try to return an array.

Thank you

Comment: Is the message you show the complete message?

Comment: You declared the symbol as an array `real, dimension(2) :: calc_derivative`  
We have several duplicates about functions returning arrays.

Comment: The best solution for similar problems is to place *all* functions and subroutines into modules.

Comment: @albert, sorry for not explaining the 'scalar part'. I have added a new section to the original question.

Comment: I don't see a new section, but the comment from Vladimir F is the best solution.

Comment: @albert just added. Since my program is small I tried to add everything in a single file. So is it not possible to add functions that return array in the  main program file ?

Comment: @VladimirF thank you for the answer. I just saw the linked question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26347090/how-to-declare-the-type-of-a-function-that-returns-an-array-in-fortran?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Note that you can have several modules and a main program in a single file. That is not any problem.